# Spring Data JPA snake_case (Table name + column name)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a SpringBoot project where I need to ensure that the table name precedes the column name in snake_case format when generating database schemas.

For example, the following entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

must convert to the `user` table with these columns:

- user_id
- user_email
- user_password
- user_created_at

Currently, I'm using the following property to convert CamleCase fields to the snake_case columns:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

So the `createdAt` field successfully converted to `created_at`, but I require it to be converted to  `user_created_at`.

is there any way to convert it automatically without using `@Column(name = "")` on each field?

Comment: You can implement your own strategy. Check this tutorial: https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/#implementing-a-custom-physical-naming-strategy

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own strategy like this

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotatedColumn;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class HibernateImplicitNamingStrategy extends 
          ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl {

@Override
public Identifier determineJoinColumnName(ImplicitJoinColumnNameSource source) {
    String name = source.getReferencedColumnName().toString().toLowerCase();
    return toIdentifier(name, source.getBuildingContext());
}

@Override
public Identifier determinePrimaryTableName(ImplicitEntityNameSource source) {
    return super.determinePrimaryTableName(source);
}

@Override
public Identifier determineBasicColumnName(ImplicitBasicColumnNameSource source) {
    try {
        Field field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        AnnotatedColumn column = (AnnotatedColumn) field.get(source);
       

        String tableName = column.getParent().getTable().getName().toLowerCase()
        final Identifier basicColumnName = super.determineBasicColumnName(source);
        String columnName = tableName + "_" + basicColumnName.toString().toLowerCase();
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(columnName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.determineBasicColumnName(source);
    }
}
}
```